# docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion stat: can't stat "..." No such file or directory

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, lets-encrypt, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm a new user of docker and probably I messed up something easy.

I'm containerizing a CodeIgniter app for what I used [phpdocker.io](https://phpdocker.io/generator). The generated docker-compose is the one that I'm using.

The plan for this containerization is that when another dev touches the code he has nothing to do more than a simple `docker-compose up` and get his hands dirty with code. The projects is using some google maps api and it requires us to install SSL on local machines (in this case, the containers).

I'm using `nginx-proxy` to map a local virtual host to the containers and it works perfectly fine, the problem comes when I'm trying to install the SSL certificates.

Here is my complete `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  ###nginx-proxy###
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ssl-data:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - ssl-data:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ssl-data:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    labels:
      - "com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy"
  ###letsencrypt###
  letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    volumes:
      - ssl-data:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - ssl-data:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ssl-data:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy
  ######mysql######
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.21
    container_name: rocatienda-mysql
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
      - ./app:/application
      - ./mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=roca-tienda
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=123456
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    depends_on:
      - letsencrypt
  whoami:
    image: jwilder/whoami
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=whoami.local
    depends_on:
      - letsencrypt
  ####webserver####
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: rocatienda-webserver
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
      - ./app:/application
      - ./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=rocatienda.local
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=rocatienda.local
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=some@example.com # this is just for this issue. I have a real email here.
    depends_on:
      - letsencrypt
  #####php-fpm#####
  php-fpm:
    build: phpdocker/php-fpm
    container_name: rocatienda-php-fpm
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
      - ./app:/application
      - ./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
    depends_on:
      - letsencrypt

volumes:
  ssl-data:
```

This is my project folder structure:

```
/roca
|-- /app
|-- /mysql_data
|-- /phpdocker
|   |-- /nginx
|   |  `-- nginx.conf
|   `-- /php-fpm
|      |-- Dockerfile
|      `-- php-ini-overrides.ini
`-- docker-compose.yml
```

These are the logs for the `docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion` container:

```
Generating a 4096 bit RSA private key
...............................................................................................................................................................++
.............................................................................++
writing new private key to '/etc/nginx/certs/default.key.new'
-----
Info: a default key and certificate have been created at /etc/nginx/certs/default.key and /etc/nginx/certs/default.crt.
Info: Creating Diffie-Hellman group in the background.
A pre-generated Diffie-Hellman group will be used for now while the new one
is being created.
Generating DH parameters, 2048 bit long safe prime, generator 2
Reloading nginx proxy (ee253de258e33e38026a4e872a0863faf4b03a27f81e8b312941dc9a905fafd4)...
2018/10/09 18:15:57 Generated '/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf' from 6 containers
2018/10/09 18:15:57 [notice] 84#84: signal process started
2018/10/09 18:15:57 Generated '/app/letsencrypt_service_data' from 6 containers
2018/10/09 18:15:57 Running '/app/signal_le_service'
2018/10/09 18:15:57 Watching docker events
2018/10/09 18:15:57 Contents of /app/letsencrypt_service_data did not change. Skipping notification '/app/signal_le_service'
/etc/nginx/certs/rocatienda.local /app
Reloading nginx proxy (ee253de258e33e38026a4e872a0863faf4b03a27f81e8b312941dc9a905fafd4)...
2018/10/09 18:15:58 Generated '/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf' from 6 containers
Creating/renewal rocatienda.local certificates... (rocatienda.local)
2018-10-09 18:15:58,957:INFO:simp_le:1382: Generating new account key
2018-10-09 18:16:01,125:INFO:simp_le:1407: By using simp_le, you implicitly agree to the CA's terms of service: https://letsencrypt.org/documents/LE-SA-v1.2-November-15-2017.pdf
ACME server returned an error: urn:acme:error:malformed :: The request message was malformed :: Error creating new authz :: Name does not end in a public suffix


Debugging tips: -v improves output verbosity. Help is available under --help.
/app
stat: can't stat '/etc/nginx/certs/accounts/acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory/default.json': No such file or directory
chown: /etc/nginx/certs/accounts/acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory/default.json: No such file or directory
stat: can't stat '/etc/nginx/certs/accounts/acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory': No such file or directory
chown: /etc/nginx/certs/accounts/acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory: No such file or directory
stat: can't stat '/etc/nginx/certs/accounts/acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org': No such file or directory
chown: /etc/nginx/certs/accounts/acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org: No such file or directory
stat: can't stat '/etc/nginx/certs/accounts': No such file or directory
chown: /etc/nginx/certs/accounts: No such file or directory
Sleep for 3600s
This is going to take a long time
Info: Diffie-Hellman group creation complete, reloading nginx.
Reloading nginx proxy (ee253de258e33e38026a4e872a0863faf4b03a27f81e8b312941dc9a905fafd4)...
2018/10/09 18:16:55 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification ''
```

You can see there is an error at the bottom of the logs. I have some questions:

- How can I fix this?
- Where did I messed things up?
- Is any other better way to accomplish what I want?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find a sollution to this?